# Did women sacrifice?

Tags: women, history, sacrifice, udhiyyah

Did women in the lifetime of Mohammad (peace be upon him) and the Sahabah offer sacrifice on eid azha?

Comment: Do you ask if they physically slaughtered the animals themselves or if an animal was slaughtered on their behalf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are narrations about various women offering udhiyya or it being slaughtered on their behalf. Some of these include:

The wives of the Prophet ﷺ:

> فلما كنا بمنى أتيت بلحم بقر فقلت ما هذا قالوا ضحى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن أزواجه بالبقر
>
> Aisha added: When we were at Mina, beef was brought to me and I asked, "What is this?" They (the people) said, "Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) has slaughtered some cows as sacrifices on behalf of his wives."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/73/4)</sup>

Fatimah, the daughter of the Prophet ﷺ:

> أن رسول الله - صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم - قال :  يا فاطمة قومي إلى أضحيتك فاشهديها ، فإنه يغفر لك عند أول قطرة تقطر من دمها كل ذنب عملتيه وقولي : إن صلاتي ونسكي ومحياي ومماتي لله رب العالمين لا شريك له وبذلك أمرت وأنا أول المسلمين
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: O Fatimah, watch your sacrifice while it is being slaughtered, because your sins will be forgiven with the first drop of blood and at that time say: "Indeed, my prayer, my rites of sacrifice, my living and my dying are for Allah, Lord of the worlds. No partner has He. And this I have been commanded, and I am the first of the Muslims." <sup>[[6:162-163](https://quran.com/6/162-164)]</sup>
>
> <sup>— [Mustadrak Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/8368), [Sunan al-Kubra](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/11827#p1), [Mu'jam  al-Kabir](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/18537)</sup>

The daughters of Abu Musa:

> وأمر أبو موسى بناته أن يضحين بأيديهن
>
> Abu Musa instructed his daughters to slaughter their sacrifices with their own hands.
>
> <sup>— Recorded by [Bukhari without a chain](https://archive.org/stream/TheTranslationOfTheMeaningsOfSahihAl-Bukhari-Arabic-English9Volumes/Sahih%20Al-Bukhari-Arabic_English_Volume-7-Ahadith-5063-5969#page/n273) ; [Untranslated arabic here](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/73/15)</sup>

Comment: The third Hadith in your answer takes me here: https://sunnah.com/bukhari/73/15

Comment: @Ahmed That is correct. As I said it is a narration without a *sanad* (chain), not a normal hadith of Bukhari. You can find the arabic text under the chapter title. The translator has not translated it though you might be able to find it translated in a print edition. Ibn Hajar in his commentary has identified a sanad and classed it as sahih.

Comment: @Ahmed I found a scan of a translated print edition [here](https://archive.org/stream/TheTranslationOfTheMeaningsOfSahihAl-Bukhari-Arabic-English9Volumes/Sahih%20Al-Bukhari-Arabic_English_Volume-7-Ahadith-5063-5969#page/n273),

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll try to look for Abu Musa's incident elsewhere too. Appreciated.